# Multi-User RVM - gem path different when using sudo to execute Ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I have installed RVM in a Multi-User configuration.  Everything seems to work, but the gem installation folder and path are different when I have to use `sudo` to execute a Ruby script.  This ends up resulting in gems not being available to a script.

If I execute `gem env` I get the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/patrickaikens/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
...
```

If I execute `sudo gem env`, I get this instead:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/patrickaikens/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /Users/patrickaikens/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
...
```

Notice that `INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY` and `GEM PATHS` are different, but both outputs indicate that RVM is "active".  I don't have a `.rvm` folder in either my own home directory or in root's home directory.  Why is RVM handling those paths differently, and can I make then the same?  Using `rvmsudo` does seem to work, but I really don't want to have to remember which of my admin scripts will run Ruby at some point if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see different information appearing when running normally and when running as "sudo" is because using sudo invokes the system ruby, bypassing RVM, rather than the version selected in your RVM.
I'm having this issue myself.

The RVM [troubleshooting page](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting) suggests using rvmsudo instead, but then also suggests you wont need to.